# JS DOM createElements and appendChild not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a website with information of some students. Hence I need to create dynamic profile cards and append them to body. But DOM always gets me.

```
function student(src, name) {
    this.src = src;
    this.name = name;
}

var student1 = student(1, "ABC");

var card = document.createElement('div');
card.className = 'card';

var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = 'images\/students\/' + student1.src + '.jpg';
card.appendChild(image);

var stuName = document.createElement('p');
stuName.className = 'name';
var stuNameText = document.createTextNode(student1.name);
stuName.appendChild(stuNameText);
card.appendChild(stuName);
```

However nothing is showing up on the screen. placeHere is the id of body. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
Apparently applying all necessary changes and moving my script tag to body helps.

Comment: You didn't append 'card' itself to body or another document's element.

Add:
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(card);

Comment: @MaxShaian Adding this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the way you creating Student1 Object is wrong 
>   `var student1 = new  student(1, "ABC");`
>   you forget new keywork

```js
function student(src, name) {
    this.src = src;
    this.name = name;
}

var student1 = new  student(1, "ABC");

var card = document.createElement('div');
card.className = 'card';

var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = 'images\/students\/' + student1.src + '.jpg';
card.appendChild(image);

var stuName = document.createElement('p');
stuName.className = 'name';
var stuNameText = document.createTextNode(student1.name);
stuName.appendChild(stuNameText);
card.appendChild(stuName);
var main=document.getElementById('main')
main.appendChild(card)
```

```css
.card{    color: palevioletred;
    background: yellow;}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: You are right about the new keyword. However this doesnt seem to work

Comment: i corrected your code in my solution you can run and test

Comment: I tried it. It works here but not on my local machine

Comment: in javascirpt add  this var main=document.getElementById('main');  main.appendChild(card) add this two line in last and in html add this tag <div id="main"></div>  As you can in my solution i added

Comment: Moving the script to body helps. Thanks for the other necessary changes by the way

Answer (score 1):

You have to append all these newly created elements to a div already in the DOM or body tag will work too. Currently, the elements you created are not attached to DOM. So lets say you have a div

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

you can append to that div you newly created elements like this:

```
ley mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
mydiv.appendChild(card);
```

or you can append it to the body itself like so:

```
ley body= document.getElementByTagName('body');
body.appendChild(card);
```

Comment: I've tried adding ```document.getElementById('placeHere').appendChild(card);``` but it doesn't work. placeHere is id of body.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't append your code to any DOM element, create new div in body and append your code into that div.
`<div id="stdCard"></div>`
and then you can use innerHTML to append card into parent div created. `document.getElementById("stdCard").innerHTML = card;`