# How do I create a button from javascript the right way

Tags: javascript

A beginners question.

I'm trying to add a button to an html document with no content.

In Chrome nothing shows up, but in the console there are no errors and I can find both btn with it's content and the div.

What's going on?

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
const btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerText = "Click me";
div.appendChild(btn);

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.style.backgroundColor("red");
});
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you `.append()` the button to the div, but not the div to the document (`body`)?

Answer (score 2):

you should append your div to the body

```html
   document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898439/js-dom-createelements-and-appendchild-not-working

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Beginner's mistake :)